# RefineryCMS + Getting Strange Output at HTML page

Tags: refinerycms

I am using RefineryCMS tool to built one application, but I am getting some strange output.

Refer the Image: 
[image]

I did not get the way to resolve it.

**UPDATE :** 
Editor : wymeditor

Answer (score 0):

Is the image from the frontpage? It looks like you have included the wymeditor stylesheets in your frontend. What does your application.css file look like?